# Dynamically create textview in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want create some text and buttons in fragment with global style

```
text = new TextView(this.getContext(),null, R.style.TxtLeds);
controlGrid.addView(text);

ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton(this.getContext(), null, R.style.SwLeds);
tb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sw_selector);
tb.setOnClickListener(this);
controlGrid.addView(tb);
```

Here is the styles xml

```
<style name="SwLeds" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 <item name="android:layout_width">160dp</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">160dp</item>
 <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
 <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
 <item name="android:button">@drawable/sw_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="TxtLeds" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:text">some text</item>
</style>
```

toggle create but not with style. It is not aligned in center. Text created, but not set  "android:text"
What is the error?

Comment: The third parameter in a `View` constructor is not for an `R.style`. It's for an `R.attr` that points to a style. If you want to pass a style directly, there is a constructor that takes an `R.style` as the fourth argument, but it's only available from Lollipop and up.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this answer.